# type 'List<Widget>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, Object>>' of 'function result'

Tags: flutter

In below code I facing problem when I access the map in body argument it will show error **object? type can't be assign to widget? type** so I use as Widget after running the I get the error which I asking here, so how to access the widget(constructor here) without getting these error.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../screens/categories_screen.dart';
import '../screens/favorites_screen.dart';

class TabsScreenBottom extends StatefulWidget {
  const TabsScreenBottom({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TabsScreenBottom> createState() => _TabsScreenBottomState();
}

class _TabsScreenBottomState extends State<TabsScreenBottom> {
  final List<Map<String, Object>> _pages = const [
    {
      'page': CategoriesScreen(),
      'title': 'Categories',
    },
    {
      'page': FavoritesScreen(),
      'title': 'My Favorites',
    },
  ];

  int _selectedPageIndex = 0;

  void _selectPage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedPageIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Meal'),
      ),
      body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'] as Widget,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
        selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        currentIndex: _selectedPageIndex,
        // type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
        // giving animation when tab is changed
        onTap: _selectPage,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.category,
            ),
            label: 'Categorey',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            // if your use type shifting
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.star,
            ),
            label: 'Favorites',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try to change List<Map<String, Object>> to List<Map<String, dynamic>>

Comment: Yes, that's worked, Thank you for your suggestion. But why the Object type is set as a key does not worked but dynamic type does? If you know then can you explain it?, Please.

Comment: I've added an answer with your query. if you think it's helpful then you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change `List<Map<String, Object>>` to `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`
and it should work.

Coming to your question:

**Why it does't work with Object type ?**

Lets look at the list item you have

```
{
 'page': CategoriesScreen(),
 'title': 'Categories',
},
```

Here on the left end side you have `String` field and hence the same we've used in the `Map`

Now if you will notice right end data type there are 2 type of values

1. `CategoriesScreen()` this is a type of `Widget`
2. `'Categories'` this is type of `String`

Hence because we have multiple type of values, we need a certain `type` that can adapt both that's why we've used `dynamic`

Comment: ok, so why here you use dynamic type instead of object type thanks for your valuable time to get me out from this issue. :):):)

Comment: because dynamic type can understand any type be it Object or be it Widget

Answer (score 1):

Once change your List<Map<String, Object>> to **List<Map<String, dynamic>>**

I hope this things are solve your issue.